# Is it possible to have multiple pub cache per project?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm on Windows 11. I have two flutter projects: A Flutter web project using flutter 3.0.4 and a flutter ios and android project using flutter 3.3.1. I switch between them using this Powershell function

```
function flu($param){
   pushd C:\flutter\
    if ($param -eq 'web') {
        git checkout -q 3.0.4
    }
    else{
        git checkout -q 3.3.1
    }
    popd
    flutter doctor -v   
}
```

The web, android, and ios have their own dependencies, and there's always be a caching problem. `flutter clean` doesn't fix it, I find myself forced to manually delete the `pub_cache` folder and then do `flutter pub get`

Is there any way to specify a different `pub_cache` folder per project?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [puro](https://puro.dev) to have multiple versions of flutter installed, selected by project.  The pub "cache" is just copies of the pub files... and should be able to be shared between your projects.